# Show two lines intersecting two disjoint planes in different points are disjoint

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I am pretty new to projective space, and I sometimes struggle with simple problems like this one.

> In a projective space $\mathbb{P}_n$, let $\pi_1, \pi_2$ be two
>   disjoint planes. If lines $l,r$ intersect the planes in different
>   points, prove $l$ and $r$ are disjoint.

I have tried to use Grassmann formula but I can't find the right way.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: How large must a projective space be to allow disjoint planes? If the lines are not disjoint, how large a space do they define?

Comment: The space must be at least dimension 5. And if the lines are not disjoint, they define another plane (they can't be the same line as they intersect the planes in different points). I got there, but I don't know how to follow.

Comment: What do you mean by "intersect the planes in different points"?

Comment: $\pi_i \cap l \not= \pi_i \cap r$

Comment: And you are requiring that for $i = 1$ and $i = 2$?. Please fix this in your question.